# Generating an MSG file in SharePoint

Tags: email, outlook

Is it possible to generate an *.MSG file on-the-fly in SharePoint 2010? This is an Outlook message file. I'd like to create an HTML message when the user clicks a button with dynamic properties from the page. Our organization uses Outlook 2010 and SharePoint is only for the intranet. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a workflow to generate an HTML email.  You can create any HTML markup you want and merge it with list/library data.  Then you can send it to the user and or send it to an email enabled document library where it will store it as a msg file.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create a custom alert template, and have that alert send the customized email to an email-enabled Document Library. I *think* the email will show up in that document library as .msg file.

Answer (score 1):

You want to generate an actual .msg file from some information within SharePoint? I've done similar, we were successful with http://www.aspose.com/, their library made creating the file real easy.

HTH